# Android, how to pass Double Value to Textview without getting infinity displayed?

Tags: android-studio, textview, double, tostring, infinity

*Short form: I try to hand over a Double Value to a textView with Double.toString but the textView always show "Infinity" instead of the true Value. When there is some Value if it's empty it shows 0.0.*

underneath i tried to explain how my app is build (constructed)

Classes:

```
MainActivity.java
FirstFragment.java
SecondFragment.java
Calculator.java
```

Layouts:

```
first_frag.xml
second_frag.xml
```

to make it easier to understand i don't post the whole code, because that would be a lot!

Basically i'm struggling at this Section in the SecondFragment.java:

```
public void fragmentBecameVisible() {
    String alcLevel = Double.toString(calc.getCurrentLevel());
    txtAlcLvl.setText(alcLevel);
}
```

Calculator.java:

```
public double getCurrentLevel(){
    double alcTotal = 0.0;

    if (consumption.size() > 0){
        alcHigh = consumption.get(0).getAlcTotal()/person.getDistribution();
        for (int i = 0; i < consumption.size()-1; i++){
            alcTotal += consumption.get(i).getAlcTotal()/person.getDistribution()
                    -(consumption.get(i+1).getDrinkTime()-consumption.get(i).getDrinkTime())*0.15/3;
            if (alcTotal < 0){
                alcTotal = 0.0;
            }
            if (alcHigh < (alcTotal + consumption.get(i+1).getAlcTotal()/person.getDistribution())){
                alcHigh = alcTotal + consumption.get(i+1).getAlcTotal()/person.getDistribution();
            }
        }
        alcTotal += consumption.get(consumption.size()-1).getAlcTotal()/person.getDistribution()
                -(consumption.get(consumption.size()-1).getTime()-consumption.get(consumption.size()-1).getDrinkTime())*0.15/3;

        if (alcTotal < 0){
            alcTotal = 0.0;
        }
        return alcTotal;
    }else{
        return 0.0;
    }
}
```

while you don't have to understand the whole math behind, it's just about the fact, that the textView from second_frag.xml:

```
            <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="New Text"
            android:id="@+id/txtAlcLvl" />
```

**does not show the correct Double Value, instead it shows "Infinity"**

I have the exact same code in Eclipse but somehow there it works just fine.

Normally i would say, i made some stupid little failure somewhere but actually i can't find it for over an hour now, maybe someone could help, would appreciate it.

Comment: person.getDistribution(), are you sure it is never zero

Comment: Man you were so right! after doing all the math to resolve another issue i lost completly the focus on set the weight and sex of the Person :/ I'm ashamed, sorry i did bother you.